# "Синий чулок": происхождение выражения

Tags: фразеология

"Синими чулками" называют педантичных строгих женщин, как правило, не интересующихся радостями жизни. Интересно, почему чулок и почему синий?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
С английского: Bluestocking.
Выражение родилось в Англии 80-х гг. XVIII в. в салоне писательницы Мэри Уортли Монтэгю (1689—1762). Душой этого салона был ученый Бенджамин Стеллингфлит (1702—1771), который, не особенно следя за своим костюмом, носил при черном платье синие чулки. Это весьма забавляло салонных дам, которые и прозвали рассеянного ученого «синим чулком» — bluestocking. А когда он по какой-то причине не приходил в назначенный час, все волновались и повторяли: «Сегодня беседа пойдет плохо — нет «синих чулок»!»
Вскоре это прозвище стало относится ко всем участникам этого кружка, где велись беседы на научные и литературные темы.
Есть версия, что кружку леди Монтэгю имя «синие чулки» дал голландский адмирал Боскавен (1711 — 1761) во время своего пребывания в Англии.
Выражение стало в Англии нарицательным после того, как поэт Джордж Гордон Байрон написал на салон леди Монтэгю сатиру (1820) и назвал ее «Синие» («The Blues»).
Вскоре выражение перешло и во Францию, где «синими чулками» (bas bleus) стали называть вполне определенный тип женщин — увлеченных научной работой, литературой в ущерб дому и семье. Из Франции выражение попало в Россию, и уже П. А. Вяземский, современник и друг А. С. Пушкина, говорил укоризненно «о наших сине- и красночу-лочницах».
Иносказательно: женщины-интеллектуалки, всецело поглощенные научными, литературными и т. п. интересами (ирон.).
```

Энциклопедический словарь крылатых слов и выражений. — М. 2003.